# Slider sliding back to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've created an horizontal slider containing multiple slides, and I've set it up so that by clicking on the nav bar arrows the slider moves to the left so the next slide takes up the screen. The total width of the slider is 500%, and it contains 5 slides that measure 20% in width each. The code looks like this:

```
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {

$(".slider").animate({marginLeft: "-=100%",}, 600);

});


$('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

$(".slider").animate({marginLeft: "+=100%",}, 600);

});
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is:

1. For the slider to slide back to its original position, 0, after arriving at its end.
2. And not to slide to the right when its at the first slide or rather at position 0.

I know its a very simple code and that there are different (and probably more efficient) ways to code an horizontal slider, but I've started coding just recently and that's the only way I've succeeded in making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final try, it takes seven div's but will only show five at a time, best I could come up with:

```js
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    $(".slider").animate({left: "-=25px"}, 600, function(){
        var left = $(this).css('left');
        $(this).css('left', left == "0px" ? "175px" : left);
    });   
});

$('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    $(".slider").animate({left: "+=25px"}, 600, function(){
        var left = $(this).css('left');
        $(this).css('left', left == "200px" ? "25px" : left);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 150px">
    <button type="button" class="arrow-prev">></button>
    <br>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: inherit; overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="before" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; height: 25px; width: 50px; background-color:white; z-index: 5; vertical-align:middle;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 25px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:red; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:purple; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 75px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:blue; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:green; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 125px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:greenyellow; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 150px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:yellow; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 175px; height: 25px; width: 25px; background-color:orange; vertical-align:middle;" class="slider"></div>
    <div id="after" style="position: absolute; left: 175px; height: 25px; width: 50px; background-color:white; z-index: 5; vertical-align:middle;"></div>
        </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>    <button type="button" class="arrow-next" style="display:inline-block">
        <</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Editing... still a  work in process... reread your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. If you need any explanation, just tell me.

```js
$.fn.createSlider = function(options){
    var container = $(options.container, this),
        slides = $(options.slides, this),
        total = slides.length,
        pos = 0,
        animating = false;

    container.width(total + '00%');
    slides.width(100 / total + '%');
    $(options.arrowLeft, this).click(previousSlide);
    $(options.arrowRight, this).click(nextSlide);
    
    function previousSlide(){
        if(!pos || animating) return;
        pos--;
        moveSliderTo(pos);
    }
    
    function nextSlide(){
        if(animating) return;
        pos++;
        if(pos == total)  pos = 0;
        moveSliderTo(pos);
    }
    
    function moveSliderTo(n){
        animating = true;
        container.animate({left: '-' + n + '00%'}, options.duration, function(){
            animating = false;
        });
    }
};

$('.slider').createSlider({
    'container' : '.slides',
    'slides' : '.slides li',
    'arrowLeft' : '.arrow-prev',
    'arrowRight' : '.arrow-next',
    'duration' : 600
});
```

```css
.slider{
    width: 65%;
    padding-top: 27.22%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1em auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slides{
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slides li{
    float: left;
}

.slides li img{
    width: 100%;
}

.arrow-prev, .arrow-next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-prev:hover, .arrow-next:hover{
    background: #fff;
}

.arrow-next{
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2088l0l.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2rfv4b6.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/9a7nk4.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/o7k7cw.jpg"/></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="arrow-prev">&lt;</div>
    <div class="arrow-next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, this code does what I want, but its complicated for someone who has just starting coding. So unfortunately I don't understand everything about it (and that is why I was going for something really simple in term of coding), but if you don't mind explaining: I don't understand the first few lines of the code and what the word 'options' and 'this' does  in $(options.container, this) and $(options.slides, this), and the last part of the code that starts with $('.slider').createSlider. I'm also confused with the use of the term 'container' (why not use 'slider' instead?)